# How I get model data without primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble updating the data I get from my database. When I want to update directly from my model object, I get this error

> **arg = {k: v for k, v in kv_generator(self, arg.items())}
> AttributeError: 'NoteORM' object has no attribute 'items'.**

How do I get the data of my model excluding the primary key?

```
class NoteORM(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Notes"

    NoteID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Reciver = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Users.UserID"))
    Note = Column(String, nullable=False)
    FilePath = Column(Text)
    IsSend = Column(String)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, onupdate=func.now())

    u_notes = relationship("UsersORM", backref="Notes")

    # getting attirbute of object
    def props(cls):   
        return [i for i in cls.__dict__.keys() if i[:1] != '_']

   
    entity = session.query(NoteORM).get(11)
    fields = props(entity) #I also get primary key :) when ı add underscore my primary key 
                           #_NoteID also get error Invalid column name '_NoteID'
```

how can i update via object, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

> how can i update via object, is there a better way?

SQLAlchemy's [Session.merge()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge) method takes care of the details for you:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base = declarative_base()


class Note(Base):
    __tablename__ = "note"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    note_text = Column(String, nullable=False)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# create an existing "note 1"
with Session(engine) as sess:
    sess.add(Note(id=1, note_text="original note 1 text"))
    sess.commit()

# create a new Note object that we can use to update "note 1"
new_note_1 = Note(id=1, note_text="new note 1 text")

# simply adding new_note_1 to the session won't work
with Session(engine) as sess:
    sess.add(new_note_1)
    try:
        sess.commit()
    except IntegrityError as ie:
        print(ie)
        """
        (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: note.id
        [SQL: INSERT INTO note (id, note_text) VALUES (?, ?)]
        [parameters: (1, 'new note 1 text')]
        """

# merging new_note_1 into the session works
engine.echo = True
with Session(engine) as sess:
    sess.merge(new_note_1)
    """
    SELECT note.id AS note_id, note.note_text AS note_note_text 
    FROM note 
    WHERE note.id = ?
    [generated in 0.00072s] (1,)
    """
    sess.commit()
    """
    UPDATE note SET note_text=? WHERE note.id = ?
    [generated in 0.00075s] ('new note 1 text', 1)
    """
```